# JS на WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Добрый день. Есть полоска сверху сайта в WP.

```
 <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <style>
       .center {
        width: 976px;
        height: 36px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: auto;
        background: #867550;
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="center">
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Нужно как то вставить такой div

```
<div id="b24formdiv_0c8dca990f7f639306ea62be5498b712" class="b24formdiv"></div>
```

Название формы (а это форма заявки с последующим отправлением оной в битрикс): "Оставить заявку". Как сделать так чтобы справа на этой полосе style появилась надпись "Оставить заявку" с гиперссылкой на открытие скрипта JS в новом пустом окне. Потому что просто вставка этого div отправляет уже открытую форму просто в угол страницы.

Comment: не смог достичь просветления. при чем тут "style", открывать скрипт в пустом окне - нужно открыть вкладку, в который исполнится js или что-то другое? попробуйте описать вопрос так, чтобы суть была понятна строннему человеку

Comment: Вроде получилось. Сделал пустую страницу на нее подкрутил JS. Теперь работает вроде бы. НО. Помоги пожалуйста. Как этот дурацкий квадратик "диалога" опустить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Пример с сайта]

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <style type="text/css">
   .center {
    width: 976px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #867550;
   }
   .email {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 150%;
   padding: 7px 5px;
   }
   .a {
   text-decoration: none;
   }
   .a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .chat {
   }
   </style>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="center">
  <div align="right" class="email"><img class="chat" height="20" width="20" src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img0002.png"><a class="a" href="mailto:**@**.ru" style="color: #FFFFFF">  Обратная связь</a></div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Вот так вывожу то что мне надо. Но нужно картнику чуть чуть вниз подвинуть (чтобы квадратик был посередине от буквы О). Никак не могу понять как это надо сделать, и каким параметром двигать. Либо сам код не правильный?

Comment: вы дополнили вопрос в поле для ответа - перенесите ваши объяснения в вопрос, отредактировав его. по теме - если ваш "квадратик" это отдельный блок, то задайте ему `position:` и используйте свойство `top:`, чтобы опустить его на нужную величину.